# Reading Data tables from feature file - Pytest-bdd

Tags: python, bdd, pytest

I am new to pytest-bdd framework.

Below is sample feature file Content:

```
Scenario Outline: Google multiple search request

  Given I want to search in Google
    When I search for '<search_request>'
    Then I should see link to '<search_result>'

  Examples:
  | search_request | search_result |
  | Pytest BDD | Python BDD - Behaviour driven development framework |
  |  Cucumber | Cucumber |
```

---

The sample python file generated from the pytest-bdd:
    # coding=utf-8
    """example.feature feature tests."""

```
from pytest_bdd import (
    given,
    scenario,
    then,
    when,
) 

 @scenario('example.feature', 'Google multiple search request')
def test_google_multiple_search_request():
    """Google multiple search request."""


@given('I want to search in Google')
def i_want_to_search_in_google():
    """I want to search in Google."""


@when('I search for '<search_request>'')
def i_search_for_search_request():
    """I search for '<search_request>'."""


@then('I should see link to '<search_result>'

Examples:
| search_request | search_result |
| Pytest BDD | Python BDD - Behaviour driven development framework |
|  Cucumber | Cucumber |
|  Cucumber2 | Cucumber2 |')
def i_should_see_link_to_search_resultexamples_search_request__search_result__pytest_bdd__python_bdd__behaviour_driven_development_framework___cucumber__cucumber___cucumber2__cucumber2_():
    """I should see link to '<search_result>'

Examples:
| search_request | search_result |
| Pytest BDD | Python BDD - Behaviour driven development framework |
|  Cucumber | Cucumber |
|  Cucumber2 | Cucumber2 |."""
```

Is there a way in pytest-bdd where it recognizes the example data set provided in the feature file and converts into valid python file like it generates the skeleton code
Or
We need to code it manually to accept the input data in the feature file

Any help much appreciated.

Regards,
Sanjay B S

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something went very wrong with the code generation. The following should not be there:

> @then('I should see link to ''
>
> Examples:
>   | search_request | search_result |
>   | Pytest BDD | Python BDD - Behaviour driven development framework |
>   |  Cucumber | Cucumber |
>   |  Cucumber2 | Cucumber2 |')

First let's fix the feature file (those single quotes are not required):

**Scenario Outline:** Google multiple search request

**Given** I want to search in Google

**When** I search for <search_request>

**Then** I should see link to <search_result>

**Examples:**

| search_request | search_result |

| Pytest BDD | Python BDD - Behaviour driven development framework |

|  Cucumber  | Cucumber |

This is how you pass a variable from your example table to the step function:

```
@when('I search for <search_request>')
def i_search_for_search_request(search_request):
    """I search for <search_request>."""
    print(search_request)
```

Hope it helps!